Finding datasheets for TVS diodes
I'm trying to find replacement parts for the SMD TVS diodes in this schematic, SL1006TS050-0R5W-11, SFI0402TS050-2R5W-11, and the D7 diode. For the first two, I've tried finding their datasheets so that I could find equivalent parts, but no luck. For the D7 diode, Google just returns some disc capacitors.
Bonus points if you could link me to some replacement parts that I could replace the current diodes with.

At least for the D7, the value label is clearly for a 100nF 25V capacitor. It is possible that the schematics were drawn with the intention of a TVS here, but changed to a capacitor because it is important, and the TVS is already on the other board where this board connects to.

The manufacturer is SFI and they aren't diodes, but MLC TVS devices (or MLC varistors) according to this product catalog (so they look like normal MLCCs).
By looking at other parts in the catalog we can deduct some of the properties from the product code:

SL1006TS050-0R5W-11
-------------------
1006: SMD package code in inch
TS: STS series
050: 5V Reverse Working Voltage
0R5: 0.5pF Parasitic Capacitance


Presumably, that means that SFI0402TS050-2R5W-11 has the following characteristics? (I apologize for the improper formatting on this. I'm not sure how to fix the Markdown)
0402: SMD package code in inch
TS: STS series
050: 5V Reverse Working Voltage
2R5: 2.5pF Parasitic Capacitance

Yes, to my understanding that's correct.

This is my first time hearing about MLC. What is that?
Also, since these aren't TVS diodes, I'm not sure what to search for on Mouser or DigiKey. Do you have any examples?

You can find some on the varistor category on mouser. There is also the Bourns Chip Guard series which is found under the TVS category. There are also a few Chinese brands that sell them, see here.
